Flask not returning Post data to React
I am experiencing issues with passing JWT tokens from my Flask backend to my React frontend and storing them in local storage. Here is the setup I am working with:

Backend: Flask
Frontend: React
Authorization: AWS Cognito

Problem Description:
I want to pass JWT tokens received from AWS Cognito to my React frontend and save them in the browser's local storage. However, I am not receiving any tokens on the frontend and instead reciving response.data as:
{
"email": null,
"password": null
}
instead of
{
"id_token": id_token,
"access_token": access_token,
"refresh_token": refresh_token,
}
My flask code for login api is:
@auth_ns.route('/login')
class Login(Resource):
    @auth_ns.marshal_with(login_model)
    @auth_ns.expect(login_model)
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json()
        if not data:
            return {'message': 'No data provided'}, 400

        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        
        client = get_cognito_client()

        try:
            response = client.initiate_auth(
                ClientId=current_app.config['COGNITO_CLIENT_ID'],
                AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
                AuthParameters={
                    'USERNAME': email,
                    'PASSWORD': password
                }
            )

            auth_result = response.get('AuthenticationResult', {})
            id_token = auth_result.get('IdToken')
            access_token = auth_result.get('AccessToken')
            refresh_token = auth_result.get('RefreshToken')
            print("ID token:", id_token)

            if not id_token or not access_token or not refresh_token:
                return {'message': 'Failed to retrieve tokens from Cognito'}, 500

            return jsonify({
                "id_token": id_token,
                "access_token": access_token,
                "refresh_token": refresh_token,
            }), 200

And react Code I am using is:
const TestLogin = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setError(null);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {
                email,
                password,
            });

            console.log('Login successful:', response.data);

            // Check if the response contains the tokens
            if (response.data.id_token && response.data.access_token && response.data.refresh_token) {
                // Save tokens to localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.id_token);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access_token);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh_token);

                // Redirect or perform other actions after successful login
            } else {
                setError('Login response did not contain tokens');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login error:', error);
            setError(error.response ? error.response.data.message : 'An error occurred');
        }
    };


I am able to sucessfully log into congito from react, and even get correct tokens from cognito. but from flask to cognito, I get response.data as
{
    "email": null,
    "password": null
}

Debugging Steps Taken:

Verified the request data and content type in Flask backend (all correct).
Printed the tokens in the backend and confirmed they are correctly retrieved.
Ensured that the Content-Type header is set to application/json.

I have tried to test it with postman and I am getitng same result. Even when I am passing something else from flask to react to test the code, I get same response
{
    "email": null,
    "password": null
}

To best of my knowledge, everything else is working fine in both frontend, backend and cognito. Only return data is not correct.
Expected Behavior:
The frontend should receive the JWT tokens in the response, allowing me to store them in local storage.
Request:
How can I successfully pass the tokens from the Flask backend to the React frontend? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
